# Adding header to http.get in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to modify the working example from deerawan to include header for another website that requires a header. I was given the solution below and it seems to work perfectly. But when I add `subscribe()`, it still works, but I get exception in console:

What should I do to fix this warning message?  Thank you.

**Original code:**

```
export class UserService {

  private serviceUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

**Solution code:**

```
export class NWSForecast {
  private config = {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'
    }
  };

  private serviceUrl = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/36,38/forecast';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<any>  {
    // first argument is URL, put config as second argument
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceUrl, this.config);
  }
}
```

**Modified solution in order to capture response. But it has exception:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  private config = {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'
    }
  };
  weathers: any;
  private serviceUrl = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/36,38/forecast';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeather() {
    this.http.get<Weather>(this.serviceUrl, this.config).subscribe(
      val => {
        this.weathers = val;
      console.log('this.weather ====> ', this.weathers);
      });
    }
}
```

The error message in console:
`Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" http.js:1436`

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? Did you read https://angular.io/guide/http?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you need to provide the URL as the first parameter to `get`.

```
 this.http.get<Weather>(url, this.config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular's `http.get()` takes 2 arguments, URL and options. You're passing them as 1 which causes this issue! Here is how I often add custom headers to my services in Angular 7:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class NWSForecast {
  private headerObj = new HttpHeaders({'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'})

  private serviceUrl = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/36,38/forecast'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<Weather>  {
    console.log(this.http.get<Weather>(this.config));
    return this.http.get<Weather>(this.serviceUrl, {headers: this.headerObj});
  }
}
```

You could also choose to pass an entire object instead of specifying the headers parameter in `http.get()`:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'
  })
};
```

And then your return would be:

```
return this.http.get<Weather>(this.serviceUrl, httpOptions);
```

I often find that the Angular documentation has pretty good examples - [Angular HTTP Guide - Adding Headers](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient), the first parameter of `HttpClient.get` is url and the second one is the configuration.

So, your code is supposed to be like below:

```
export class NWSForecast {
  private config = {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'
    }
  };

  private serviceUrl = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/36,38/forecast';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<any>  {
    // first argument is URL, put config as second argument
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceUrl, this.config);
  }
}
```

Tested that it works

[image]